# Is it possible to get the non-interpolated value of an attribute in AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

When I read an attribute in an AngularDart component, I get the interpolated value. The mustaches are replaced the the actual values. Most of the time that's fine by me.

However, the component I'm currently writing also needs to know the formal parameter (i.e. what the attribute looks like in the source code, without being interpolated). Is it possible to retrieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Albeit I haven't found the answer to my question yet, there's a work-around: I moved the code to the constructor. At construction time interpolation hasn't happened yet.